# How do I properly format interpolated ruby objects as jquery selectors in rails, using haml?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

```
<% if @discussion_category %>
 $("#<%= dom_id(@discussion_category) %>_notice").html('');
 $("#<%= dom_id(@discussion_category) %>").html("<%=escape_javascript(render(partial: 'display_change', locals: {discussion_category: @discussion_category}))%>");
 $('#discussion_category_links').show();
<% end %>
```

I did the following, but I'm doing something wrong:

```
-if @discussion_category
  javascript:
    $(escape_javascript(#{dom_id(@discussion_category)} + '_notice').html('');
    $(escape_javascript(#{dom_id(@discussion_category)}).html(#{escape_javascript(render(partial: 'display_change', locals: {discussion_category: @discussion_category}))});
    $('#discussion_category_links').show();
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Your first 2 lines with **escape_javascript** are missing matching closing parenthesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `escape_javascript` function is on the rails side.  You don't want it in the output so it'd be within the `#{}`.

And you threw out most the quotes.  Still need those.

Hopefully there's no typos but a direct translation should look more like this:

```
-if @discussion_category
  javascript:
    $("#{escape_javascript(dom_id(@discussion_category))}_notice").html('');
    $("#{escape_javascript(dom_id(@discussion_category))}")
      .html("#{escape_javascript(render(partial: 'display_change', locals: {discussion_category: @discussion_category}))}");
    $('#discussion_category_links').show();
```

When building messy RJS stuff like this it can be much cleaner looking to use the `j` alias for `escape_javascript`, which would help in narrowing down syntax issues as well:

```
javascript:
  $("#{j dom_id(@discussion_category)}_notice").html('');
  $("#{j dom_id(@discussion_category)}")
    .html("#{j render(partial: 'display_change', locals: {discussion_category: @discussion_category})}");
```

Finally, there's probably no reason to escape the output of `dom_id`, meaning you could just:

```
javascript:
  $("#{dom_id @discussion_category}_notice").html('');
  $("#{dom_id @discussion_category}")
    .html("#{j render(partial: 'display_change', locals: {discussion_category: @discussion_category})}");
```

... which is beginning to look a lot more readable.

Comment: Thanks!  This is the perfect explanation!